# ReactJS: How do you call an async fuction on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

How can I call fetchData() on button a click ?
Should i call the fucntion using useEffect ?

```
function Subscriptions() {
  const [allUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData = async () => {
      try {
       // some code
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
  }, []);
  return (

<Button onclick={fetchData()}>Fetch Data</Button>

);
}
export default Subscriptions;
```

Comment: You use `useEffect` to "react" to prop or state changes, not user interaction.

Comment: You're calling `fetchData` immediately and passing the result of calling that function to the listener instead of passing a _reference_ to the function that the listener can use: `onClick={fetchData}`.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchData` is in a different nested scope and therefore not accessible to the button component. Use `useCallback` to define an async callback:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

function Subscriptions() {
  const [allUsers] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      // some code
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);
  return <Button onClick={fetchData}>Fetch Data</Button>;
}
export default Subscriptions;
```

Comment: There is no IIFE here. Also you either want `onclick={fetchData}` or `onclick={() => fetchData()}` (if arguments need to be passed to `fetchData`).

Comment: @FelixKling I accidentally hit post prematurely

Comment: OK, now there is an IIFE... but whats the point? Why not just pass that function to `useCallback`? `useCallback(async () => { ... })`.

Comment: @FelixKling now that you mention it, async IIFE's are only required in useEffect where the return value can't be a promise

Answer (score 0):

useEffect hook called at load time .
you should define fetchData function outside of useEffect
actually you dont need useEffect for this situation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a function then call on both times in useEffect as well as onClick.

```
function Subscriptions() {
      const [allUsers] = useState([]);
      const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
           // some code
         } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
         }
      };      
     useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
     }, []);
      return (
        <Button onclick={()=>fetchData()}>Fetch Data</Button>
      );
    }
    export default Subscriptions;
```